# Why TFlite python api is faster than C++ one?

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am working on a project where I need to use TFlite C++ api. I have done it before, using Python. However, the problem is that inference from model using C++ api is almost 5 times slower than the Python one. The models are mediapipes hand and palm tflite models. Can I learn the reason why C++ inference is slower than Python? Is there any solution to make it faster? Below I have attached both Python and C++ code of the relevant part. Thank you very much.

Python inference:

```
self.interp_joint.set_tensor(self.in_idx_joint, img_norm.reshape(1, 224, 224, 3))
joints = self.interp_joint.get_tensor(self.out_idx_joint)
```

C++ inference:

```
float* input_data_ptr = hand_landmarks_interpreter->typed_tensor<float>(in_idx_hand);
memcpy(input_data_ptr, img_norm.data, img_norm.total() * img_norm.elemSize());
hand_landmarks_interpreter->Invoke();
TfLiteIntArray *output_dims = hand_landmarks_interpreter->tensor(out_idx_hand)->dims;
auto output_size = output_dims->data[output_dims->size - 1];
float* result = hand_landmarks_interpreter->typed_tensor<float>(out_idx_hand);
```

Note: The part that takes a lot of time is `invoke` command. In both cases images are reshaped to correct size of (224, 224, 3) and they are in CV_32FC3 type.

CMakeLists.txt content (I am using cmake to build my project in Visual Studio Code environment.):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(main C CXX)

set(TENSORFLOW_SOURCE_DIR "C:/MyApps/Tensorflow/tensorflow_src" CACHE PATH
  "Directory that contains the TensorFlow project"
)

if(NOT TENSORFLOW_SOURCE_DIR)
  get_filename_component(TENSORFLOW_SOURCE_DIR
    "C:/MyApps/Tensorflow/tensorflow_src"
    ABSOLUTE
  )
endif()

find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})

add_subdirectory(
  "C:/MyApps/Tensorflow/tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite"
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/tensorflow-lite"
  EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL
)

add_compile_options(-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++)

set(SOURCES main.cpp hand_tracker.cpp non_max_suppression_fast.cpp
             ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/hand_tracker.h ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/non_max_suppression_fast.h)
             
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
add_executable(main
  ${SOURCES}
)

target_link_libraries(main
  tensorflow-lite
  ${OpenCV_LIBS}
)
```

Comment: Did you turn on optimizations when you compiled the C++ code?

Comment: Indeed I am using CMake file for building the project. I didn't add anything for optimization. I will include my CMakeLists.txt also. Thanks for the fast response.

Comment: I've not used CMake so I'm not exactly sure where to put it but if you add `-O2` or `-O3` to `add_compile_options`, does it make the code faster?

Comment: I tried to add optimization level, but it didn't affect anything.

Comment: I am very thankful to you. As you have said, the problem was due to the optimization.

Comment: Did you figure out how to make it run fast? 
I have the same issue, I want to use Mediapipe With CMake, and since Mediapipe doesn't support CMake I thought I could implement the hand and palm tflite models directly inside my code. And is there any chance to take a look at your code

Comment: and I'm wondering did you resize the image twice? one as 192*192 for palm and again 224*224 for hand?

Answer (score 0):

Per default your implementation probably just uses a single CPU core when running C++. However, in Python the load gets distributed over the cores. This makes the execution significately faster! Last time I did not have the time to look into how we can infer tflite faster on CPU using C++, I just exported everything as a Python library and ran it there :/ But maybe someone can give some more insight (or I find time to look it up) on how one can run the inference using multiple cores. Sure you can give TensorFlow more threads. This increases the speed but it still does not get as fast as the python library which is built around it.